# Changing the format of a table using awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've got an input file (input.txt):

```
col1 1 10 ID1 1.5
col1 1 10 ID2 2.4
col2 15 25 ID1 2.1
col2 15 25 ID2 6.2
col3 30 40 ID1 0.4
col3 30 40 ID2 1.9
col4 45 55 ID1 0.1
col4 45 55 ID2 0.2
```

And I need to change the format of the table above to be like below:

```
ID col1:1-10 col2:15-25 col3:30-40 col4:45-55
ID1 1.5 2.1 0.4 0.1
ID2 2.4 6.2 1.9 0.2
```

1) From the input file, $1,$2,and $3 becomes the headers for the output file. $1":"$2"-"$3

2) $4 of the input file becomes the row names

3) $5 of the input file becomes the values within the table, filling in the output table depending on which row name and which column name it corresponds to.

Since we don't know how many columns or rows the output table will have without going through the input file at least once, I started by getting the column names

```
awk '{a[$1,":",$2,"-",$3]++} END {for(b in a) { print b} }' input.txt 

col1:1-10
col4:45-55
col3:30-40
col2:15-25
```

and the IDs

```
awk '{a[$4]++} END {for(b in a) { print b} }' input.txt

ID1
ID2
```

Can the problem be solved by running through the file once? I can't really think of a way to accomplish it using awk/sed..

Comment: Use two arrays, one for the `colX`, another for the `IDx`, and assign them both. Then the `END` block loops through both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    numCols = ++colCnt[$4] + 1
    numRows = ++rowCnt[$1] + 1
    cell[1,1] = "ID"
    cell[1,numCols] = $1":"$2"-"$3
    cell[numRows,1] = $4
    cell[numRows,numCols] = $5
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", cell[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ID col1:1-10 col2:15-25 col3:30-40 col4:45-55
ID1 1.5 2.1 0.4 0.1
ID2 2.4 6.2 1.9 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two different arrays. Assign them both during the file processing, and loop through both at the end.

```
awk '{colnum = substr($1, 4); if (colnum > maxcol) maxcol = colnum;
      cols[colnum]  = $1 ":" $2 "-" $3; 
      ids[$4] = ids[$4] " " $5} 
     END {for(i = 1; i <= maxcol; i++) print cols[i];
          for (id in ids) print id, ids[id] }' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but the answer isn't quite correct because the order of the header doesn't match up the the rest of the values in the table.
For example col4:45-55 is matched up with 2.1 (ID1) and 6.2 (ID2)

Comment: `awk` associative arrays don't keep the original order. You can pipe it to `sort`.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean? Do you mean sort the ids array before printing it?

Comment: `awk '...' input.txt | sort`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "order of the header". What header are you talking about?

Comment: Are the `colX` things supposed to be column headings? I'm printing them on separate lines, like in your script.

Comment: Yup they are column headings so not supposed to be on separate lines. Same with the rows starting with "ID1" and "ID2", they are supposed to be on one line :)

Comment: See updared answer. I get the column number from the colX field, and then iterate from 1 to the highest value.